# wordpress create post from image upload

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some code to create posts from uploading images into the media library, which is working fine:

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'create_post');
function create_post( $attach_ID ) {

$attachment = get_post( $attach_ID );

$my_post_data = array(
            'post_title' => $attachment->post_title,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_category' => array('0'),
            'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post_data );

// attach media to post
wp_update_post( array(
    'ID' => $attach_ID,
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
) );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_ID );

return $attach_ID;
}
```

The catch is that I don't want it to create new posts from an image upload if  I'm manually creating a post. In other words, I want the code to create new posts only if I upload images directly into the media library, not when I added images manually into a new post.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from a developer on Wizpert. He used the below code to make it work

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'create_post');

function create_post( $attach_ID ) {

$attachment = get_post( $attach_ID );

if(!$attachment->post_parent)
{
    $my_post_data = array(
    'post_title' => $attachment->post_title,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array('0'),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post_data );

    // attach media to post
    wp_update_post( array(
    'ID' => $attach_ID,
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
    ) );

    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_ID );

    return $attach_ID;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but you could use the global variable $pagenow.

```
global $pagenow;
if($pagenow == 'upload.php'){
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Hi There,

Thanks for the response. I did give it a try, but no luck. Does it matter that I'm doing this in my functions.php page?

Comment: No, is not relevant, i think that your objective is not so easy to reach... Wordpress by default create a new attachment post type for each media that you upload. Your script duplicate the attachment entity. You should modify the Wordpress logic, if i understand correctly your question.